# Using ReGex in shortcuts, encountering inconsistent behavior

Tags: shortcuts-app

I'm using shortcut to input and append info to a note document. The issue is that I'm trying to escape all the quotes and apostrophes in my inputs, but some might already be escaped so I have to do so selectively. The command I made for this in shortcuts was `Replace (?<!\\)(['"]) with \\$1 in Text`, I have case sensitive and regular expression enabled. My test string is

> Hello there it's me, don\'t escape this one. "One quote" followed by \"another\"
>
> Testing new date format and some escape characters like " and it's

Which then becomes

> Hello there it\'s me, don\'t escape this one. \"One quote\" followed by \"another\"
>
> Testing new date format and some escape characters like " and it's

So for whatever reason it isn't replacing anything on the second line with the escaped versions. I built this ReGex over at https://regexr.com/ where it matches all the strings in the input I give so it should work as far as I can tell, and it's not like the negative look behind isn't supported since it works fine in the first line. I also tried adding a separate " ' after the second line to see if it'd get escaped and those ones did, but the ones already in that line didn't. If anyone could explain what's going on here and how to deal with it or suggest a better ReGex that would be very helpful, thank you.

I uploaded pictures of both tests to make it clear what I'm seeing/dealing with.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I cross posted this to stack overflow since it's ReGex focused so I wasn't sure if the issue was in that or the apple app, [here's a link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68137486/13191722) to that post, I was advised to change my ReGex to \\*(['"]) and now it does replace the quotation mark on the second line but not the apostrophe, so still not solved.